# Multiple selection in ListView

Tags: android, listview, selection

I followed [this link](https://techienotes.info/2015/09/13/how-to-select-multiple-items-in-android-listview/) for multiple selection of `ListView`.

I want to know if there is any way user can restrict the selection on view depends on case.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `user can restrict the selection on view depends on case`?

Comment: I have two screen lets say A and B.user select count 2 on first screen then go to screen which is list screen, here user can only select not more than 2 row and return selected value on first screen A.

Comment: You need a custom adapter for that.